# What's the Groovy equivalent to Python's dir()?

Tags: python, groovy

In Python I can see what methods and fields an object has with:

```
print dir(my_object)
```

What's the equivalent of that in Groovy (assuming it has one)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks particulary nice in Groovy (untested, [taken from this link](http://noor.ojuba.org/2008/07/groovy-introspection-know-what-you-have/) so code credit should go there):

```
// Introspection, know all the details about classes :
// List all constructors of a class
String.constructors.each{println it}

// List all interfaces implemented by a class
String.interfaces.each{println it}

// List all methods offered by a class
String.methods.each{println it}

// Just list the methods names
String.methods.name

// Get the fields of an object (with their values)
d = new Date()
d.properties.each{println it}
```

The general term you are looking for is **introspection**.

Answer (score 7):

As described [here](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/05/07/what-methods-does-my-groovygrails-class-have/), to find all methods defined for String object:

```
 "foo".metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique()
```

It's not as simple as Python version, perhaps somebody else can show better way.

Answer (score 0):

Besides just using the normal Java reflection API, there's:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/JN3535-Reflection

You can also play games with the metaclasses.