# What's the Groovy equivalent to the no-arguments version of Python's dir()?

Tags: groovy, scope, introspection

In Python, at runtime, you can get a list of the variable names currently in scope with [**dir()**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir).  Is there a way to do the same thing in Groovy?

**dir(someobject)** can also be used to inspect an object, but that's not what this question is about.  That functionality is already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882469/whats-the-groovy-equivalent-to-pythons-dir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a groovy [script](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Script.html), you can inspect the [binding](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html):

```
binding.variables.each{  
  println it.key 
  println it.value  
}
```

There is no direct equivalent to Python's `dir`. However, there is at least [one technique](http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/knowing-which-variables-are-bound-or-not-in-a-groovy-script) you can use to find which variables are in scope.

Comment: Thanks.  "There is no direct equivalent" answers the question.  The linked technique is over my head, but it definitely doesn't deliver what I was hoping for:  a line or two of code I could insert in a large application to print out the variables in scope at that point.  A breakpoint in an IDE would serve the same purpose, but I can't get breakpoints working consistently for Groovy in Eclipse.